# StackExchange.Redis - StackExchangeRedisCacheClient - timeout issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, stackexchange.redis

i am using the DLL StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Newtonsoft for storing the data in REDIS, below is the code which i am using, but am getting the below error.

Timeout performing GET redis_key (5000ms), inst: 0, qs: 1, in: 0, serverEndpoint: , mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: , IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=4,Max=32767), v: 2.0.513.63329 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:

```
 using (var redisClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(serializer, $"{StrRedisCacheIPAddress}:{IRedisCachePort.ToString()}"))
            {
                var endPointData = redisClient.Get<List<EndPoint>>(listName);
                if (endPointData != null)
                {
                    EndPoint endPoint = endPointData.Where(x => x.Hostname == key && x.CustomerID == customerId).LastOrDefault();
                    result = endPoint.Contents;
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
```

Please let me know the solution for this.

Comment: I'd suggest having a longer timeout.

Comment: i have increased timeout, still the same issue.

Comment: Likely you are selecting and endpoint that does not exist.  Suggest logging your Endpoints so you can see what is being searched for vs. what endpoints exist.

Comment: This helped me, I did not have targetFramework in my httpRuntime tag in my web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/993854/all-redis-commands-timing-out-when-using-azure-cac.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue solved with below connection string to the REDIS using StackExchnage.

```
6379,allowAdmin=true,ConnectTimeout=30000,connectRetry=5,syncTimeout=30000,abortConnect=false
```